# Constraint on row value based on values in other rows

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints, exclusion-constraint

Is it possible to have a table with four columns:

```
CREATE TABLE accrual (
    add_date date NOT NULL,
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    rate integer NOT NULL,
    amount numeric(7,3)
);
```

and then constrain it so that if I already have one entry like

```
('2016-04-01', 3, 120, 25.6)
```

an attempt to insert another entry with the same date and user_id but a different rate would fail?  i.e.

```
('2016-04-01', 3, 140, 15)
```

would fail, but

```
('2016-04-02', 3, 140, 15)
```

or

```
('2016-04-01', 4, 140, 15)
```

or

```
('2016-04-01', 3, 120, 15)
```

would be fine?

To be clear, the date and user_id are basically like an index, except duplicate indices are totally fine as long as the rates are the same.  The amount is not constrained.

I am working with a postrgesql 9.5 database, and I am using PHP.  My guess is that the easiest thing to do is to write some PHP code to perform the check.  The closest question I could find to this was this one:

[trigger or check constraint insert values based upon existence of others](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98365/trigger-or-check-constraint-insert-values-based-upon-existence-of-others)

but it is about an Oracle database and is slightly different.

Thanks for any suggestions!!!

Comment: Exclusion constraint might work here. see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE . Else you'll need a trigger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @NeilMcGuigan suggested, an Exclusion Constraint is the key here.  The part I was unfamiliar with was the ability to use the <> operator.  As available post Postgres 9.0:

```
CREATE TABLE accrual (
    add_date date NOT NULL,
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    rate integer NOT NULL,
    amount numeric(7,3),
    EXCLUDE USING gist
        (date WITH =,
        user_id WITH =,
        rate WITH <>)
);
```

Two helpful links are:

1. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_constraints.htm -- a short tutorial on constraints in Postgres, with an example for the Exclusion constraint that uses the <> operator

and

2. http://www.slideshare.net/pgconf/not-just-unique-exclusion-constraints (specifically slide 23) -- a presentation on the need for and use of Exclusion constraints.  Slide 23 introduces the <> operator and its usefulness.

Comment: Nice one! Glad you figured it out